# Passing Navigator object in renderItem

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm struggling to make `Navigator` object visible in `List` Component.
Here the code explained: as you can see in `RootDrawer`, I have `Concept` component. It simply shows a list of items based on a `id` passed in `param`.
Each item points to another `Concept` with another id, but I get

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
```

when I press on that `<RippleButton>` with `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Concept',{id:12})`. The problem here I'm not passing the Navigation object correctly. How can I solve?

main Navigator drawer

```
const RootDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
    {

        Home: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
                Home: { screen: Home }
            })
        },
        Search: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
                Cerca: { screen: Search },
                Concept: { screen: Concept },
            })
        }
    }
);
```

Concept component

```
export default class Concept extends Component {

    loading = true
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation,state }) => ({
        headerTitle: "",
        title: `${navigation.state.params.title}` || "",
    })
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
    }

    render() {
        const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
        const id = params ? params.id : null;
        const { t, i18n, navigation } = this.props;
        const Concept = DB.get(id)


        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <List data={Concept.array|| []} title={"MyTile"} navigation={navigation} />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

List Component

```
class List extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
    }
    _renderItem = (item,navigation) => (
        <RippleButton
            id={item.id}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Concept', { id: 12, otherParam: 'anything you want here'})}> //this line throws the error
            <Text>{item.Term}</Text>

        </RippleButton>

    )

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => this._renderItem(item, navigation)}
                />
            </View>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the navigation prop, you can try using the `withNavigation` HOC.

Where your List Component is defined:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation`

....


export default withNavigation(List)
```

Now the List component will have access to the `navigation` prop

Comment: I'm pretty sure `StackNavigator` is correct with my version of react-navigation. This is part of my package.json ` "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",  "react-native": "0.54.0","react-navigation": "^1.5.11" `
I cannot update the whole project right now

Comment: hm yep that is right for 1.x, I changed my answer to something else you could try

Comment: it works, but are you sure there is no proper solution without HOC? Mine is a pretty common usage..

Comment: technically this is a proper solution, this is an API offered by the library as an alternative to passing the navigation prop. That being said, I don't see anything wrong with your code as far as passing the prop down. I'm certain that passing the prop does work, as I do so in my own apps, but I do not see any issues in the code you've posted so it's possible the problem is elsewhere. Try logging the value of the `navigation` prop as you pass it along and see if there is a spot where it becomes `undefined`

Comment: heres the relevant documentation for `withNavigation` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/1.x/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Comment: I will convert the app to the up-to-date react-navigation release as soon as possible and check if the problem is still there, thanks (quick unrelated question: there are examples around the web about Drawer and nested StackNavigators? I'm not sure it's the way to go)

Comment: I'm not aware of any examples off hand but it's a perfectly acceptable pattern in react-navigation. Generally you'll use either tabs or a drawer as your top level navigator, and then stacks for any nested navigators, and maybe a nested tab nav if you have a justifiable use case